# module 'csv' has no attribute 'writerow'

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to write a list to a csv file using:

```
import csv

with open('filename.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr = csv.writerow(list)
```

returns the error:

```
module 'csv' has no attribute 'writerow'
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please _read the module's documentation_ before asking on SO (or anywhere else). The documentation is there _exactly for you_, to teach you how to use the module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call `writerow()` on your `writer`-instance - not on `csv`:

Straigth from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

> ```
> import csv
> with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
>     spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
>                             quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
>     spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
>     spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
> ```

Comment: That was it, thanks! (I'll 'accept' the answer in 7 minutes lol).